# How do I use MacPorts to downgrade a dynamic library?

Tags: linker, macports, dynamic-linking, mysql

My py-mysql is farking because I've upgraded MySQL which replaced `libmysqlclient_r.15.dylib` with `libmysqlclient_r.16.dylib`. How do I find and get back the older version?

EDIT: I found that to intall an older version of MySQL, I need to do @, but I'm still looking for the way to find the older versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing older versions is a pain. You have to grab the files from the [MacPorts SVN Repository](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports), which is tricky, since you can't directly search for a particular version. Once you've downloaded the appropriate portfile, it's easy as installing any other port. Read the official [how to install an older version of a port](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort) document for the details. There's also an [older procedure](http://journal.bitshaker.com/articles/2007/10/20/install-old-versions-of-ports-using-macports/) that has you add the downloaded port to a local port repository.

Answer (score 3):

Didn't figure out how to find older versions (please answer still, I'll accept). But the way I fixed it was to activate the older version:

```
dreBook:~ fedorov$ port installed mysql5
The following ports are currently installed:
  mysql5 @5.0.81_0
  mysql5 @5.1.40_0 (active)
dreBook:~ fedorov$ sudo port activate mysql5 @5.0.81_0
--->  Deactivating mysql5 @5.1.40_0
--->  Activating mysql5 @5.0.81_0
dreBook:~ fedorov$ sudo apachectl restart
```

Yay!

Comment: This is the preferred solution, as long as the older version is still installed.